# MikTeX can’t find xstring

Tags: packages, miktex, xstring

I’m not using MikTeX myself but someone I developed a class for. And it seems like there’s a problem with `xstring`. The following MWE compiles fine with my TeX Live 2012 but MikTeX (on Win 7) can’t find the package, although it seem to be installed correctly installed. Furthermore MikTeX should install missing packages on the fly, shouldn’t it (the feature is activated)?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

[image: package manager]

[image: installed files]

Comment: That's an error in the miktex package. xstring.tex is missing. The bug has already been reported. Until the package is updated: Get `xstring.tex` from CTAN manually and put it somewhere where it can be found (e.g. in your current folder, or in a local texmf).

Comment: Bug tracker is (not clear from the miktex home page) at http://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2185/

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thank you, if you post an answer I’ll accept it, or should this question be closed?

Comment: @cyberSingularity: Thanks but I wasn’t sure if this is a bug since I’m not familiar with MikTeX …

Comment: I got the file from CTAN and placed it in Miktex 2.9\tex\latex\xstring under win 7 and unfortunately this is not working out for me... any sugeestions?

Comment: Remember to run `initexmf --update-fndb`.

Comment: Or `Start Menu-> MikTeX->Settings (admin)-> Refresh FNDB`.

Comment: yes thanks, I just found out... ;) Before that I copied xstring in generic, however now it works...